# Why Future.sequence executes my futures in parallel rather than in series?

Tags: scala, future

The word "*sequence*" means a **series** of actions one after the other.

```
object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    def producer() = {
      val list = Seq(
          future { println("startFirst"); Thread.sleep(3000); println("stopFirst") }, 
          future { println("startSecond"); Thread.sleep(1000); println("stopSecond") }
      )
      Future.sequence(list)
    }

   Await.result(producer, Duration.Inf)
  }
}
```

Therefore I expect this program to print: 

`startFirst
stopFirst
startSecond
stopSecond`

or even:

`startSecond
stopSecond
startFirst
stopFirst`

but not (as it happens): 

`startFirst
startSecond
stopSecond
stopFirst`

Why this method is not called `Future.parallel()`? 
And what should I use to guarantee that all futures in a  `Seq` of futures are triggered serially (as opposed to in parallel) ?

Comment: It's a sequence of *results*, not sequence of *effects*

Comment: Also, I guess the name comes from monad sequence.

Comment: You can also accomplish the result with this code http://stackoverflow.com/a/41657239

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The futures are running concurrently because they have been started concurrently :).
To run them sequentially you need to use flatMap:

```
Future { println("startFirst"); 
         Thread.sleep(3000); 
         println("stopFirst") 
        }.flatMap{
         _ =>  Future { 
                       println("startSecond"); 
                       Thread.sleep(1000); 
                       println("stopSecond") 
               }
        }
```

Future.sequence just turns `Seq[Future[T]] => Future[Seq[T]]` which means gather results of all already started futures and put it in future .

Comment: sequence is M[Future[A]] => Future[M[A]]

Answer (score 19):

a little change to the original Future.sequence will make the future execution serialized:

```
def seq[A, M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](in: M[() => Future[A]])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[()=>Future[A]], A, M[A]], executor: ExecutionContext): Future[M[A]] = {
    in.foldLeft(Future.successful(cbf(in))) {
       (fr, ffa) => for (r <- fr; a <- ffa()) yield (r += a)
    } map (_.result())
}
```

and your code will look like this:

```
object Test {
def main(args: Array[String]) {

    def producer() = {
      val list = Seq(
          {() => future { println("startFirst"); Thread.sleep(3000); println("stopFirst") }}, 
          {() => future { println("startSecond"); Thread.sleep(1000); println("stopSecond") }}
      )
      FutureExt.seq(list)
    }

    Await.result(producer, Duration.Inf)
    }
}
```

which is very like your original code and with same result collection with the original Future.sequence()

Comment: What are your motivations to name the values fr and ffa as such? I can't find an acronym matching this naming

Answer (score 5):

Linearize:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.collection.mutable.Builder
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import language.higherKinds

/**
 * Linearize asynchronously applies a given function in-order to a sequence of values, producing a Future with the result of the function applications.
 * Execution of subsequent entries will be aborted if an exception is thrown in the application of the function.
 */
def linearize[T, U, C[T] <: Traversable[T]](s: C[T])(f: T => U)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[C[T], U, C[U]], e: ExecutionContext): Future[C[U]] = {
  def next(i: Iterator[T], b: Builder[U, C[U]]): Future[C[U]] = if(!i.hasNext) Future successful b.result else Future { b += f(i.next()) } flatMap { b => next(i, b) }
  next(s.toIterator, cbf(s))
}

scala> linearize(1 to 100)(_.toString) foreach println

scala> Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100)
```

From: https://gist.github.com/viktorklang/3347939

Answer (score 3):

If you have a sequence of some values and you want to map them to `Future`'s and execute them in series:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

implicit class SeqExtension[A](s: Seq[A]) {
  def foldLeftToFuture[B](initial: B)(f: (B, A) => Future[B])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[B] =
    s.foldLeft(Future(initial))((future, item) => future.flatMap(f(_, item)))

  def mapInSeries[B](f: A => Future[B])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Seq[B]] =
    s.foldLeftToFuture(Seq[B]())((seq, item) => f(item).map(seq :+ _))
}

val stringsFuture: Future[Seq[String]] = Seq(1, 2, 3).mapInSeries[String](i => Future(i.toString))
val strings = Await.result(stringsFuture, Duration.Inf) // List("1", "2", "3")
```

Answer (score 2):

or you can use for {..} yield block to get sequence of Future. Future.sequence convert Seq[Future] to Future[Seq]

Comment: The problem with for..yield is approach is that I can insert in the for block futures one by one, but I have a Seq of them!

Comment: probably you can then try map(). There are few vendor specific implementation of future(typesafe,twitter), i guess you might want one mentioned here at twitter scala school called "concurrent composiiton" https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/finagle.html#futconcurrent

Comment: Note: The futures in for comprehension are executed sequentially only if they are also defined in the for comprehension. If you use already defined futures the for comprehension doesn't help with sequentiality.

Comment: +1 IMO for comprehensions are clearer syntactically than flatmap once you understand the for comprehensions.