# Executing N times a Scala Future

Tags: scala, http, asynchronous

I am trying to find a more elegant way to execute 2 times a function which returns a Future[HttpReponse] and then to use the response of the 2-end call.

```
for {
    // function post returns a Future[HttpResponse]
    response <- post(uri, payload) // 1st
    response <- post(uri, payload) // 2end
} yield {
    // do something with the 2end response
}
```

This does not work:

```
for {
    2 times response <- post(uri, payload)
} yield {
    // response becomes of type Any instead of HttpResponse
}
```

Comment: Should the the 2 calls be executed concurrently or sequentially?

Comment: Sequentially :-)

Comment: Updated my answer to work sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be all:

```
val result = Seq.fill(2)(post(uri, payload)).last
```

I tested this with this code:

```
 val result = Seq.fill(2)(dummyFut()).last

  def dummyFut(): Future[Long] = Future.successful{
    Thread.sleep(1000L)
    println(System.currentTimeMillis())
    System.currentTimeMillis()
  }

  result.foreach(println)
```

This prints:

```
1552852972738
1552852973749
1552852973749
```

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly, it works for me with <- operator instead of = one. But still, this is what I was looking for. :-)

Comment: @Martin This doesn't actually run the futures sequentially. It only looks like it in the example because pme's using `Future.successful`, which runs the provided code on the same thread, instead of `Future.apply`. Replace `Future.successful {` with `Future {` and you will see that it doesn't print the right times.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon thanks for pointing that out - so I just was lucky;(.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to make two sequential calls to a method that returns `Future`, you can use `flatMap`.

```
post(uri, payload).flatMap(_ => post(uri, payload))
```

This will not start the second `post` operation until the first one completes.

If you have multiple chained calls you can use `foldLeft` on a `Range` to apply this the appropriate number of times:

```
(0 to N-1).foldLeft(post(uri, payload)){
  case (prev, _) => prev.flatMap(_ => post(uri, payload))
}
```

In practice you would probably use the value from the `Range` to track progress on this operation rather than discarding it.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would want something like this:

```
Future.sequence(Stream.fill(n)(post(uri, payload)))
```

However, if you really want it to be sequential, this doesn't work, as `Future.sequence` evaluates the `Stream` eagerly and starts all futures in parallel. There are some solutions to that problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056957/why-future-sequence-executes-my-futures-in-parallel-rather-than-in-series). For example, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42416951/2093695) user [eagle yuan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5967170/eagle-yuan)'s version of sequence that works sequentially:

> ```
> def seq[A, M[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](in: M[() => Future[A]])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[()=>Future[A]], A, M[A]], executor: ExecutionContext): Future[M[A]] = {
>     in.foldLeft(Future.successful(cbf(in))) {
>        (fr, ffa) => for (r <- fr; a <- ffa()) yield (r += a)
>     } map (_.result())
> }
> ```

You can use it like:

```
seq(Seq.fill(n)(() => post(uri, payload)))
```