# For-comprehension semi-parallel calls in scala

Tags: scala, future, scala-collections, for-comprehension

I want to make first call in seq to next ones but then next 10 calls parallel to each other using Scala's futures. I dont want to program map flatmaps or for inside for comprehensions as they'll add on to unreadibility. Is it possible with one for comprehension.

reference code:

```
val fcaAndFplAccountDetails  = getFcaAndFplAccount(fplId)
def orgDetailsIO(orgId:Int)  = getOrgDetails(orgId)
def unbilledTxns(orgid: Int) = getUnbilledTxns(orgId)
for {
      accDetails   <- fcaAndFplAccountDetails
      orgDetails   <- orgDetailsIO(accDetails.orgId)
      unbilledTxns <- unbilledTxnsIO(accDetails.orgId)
      ... other calls that depend on org id
    } yield { ... further computations }
```

**Can the calls after `fcaAndFplAccountDetails` be parallelized within the comprehension?**

Comment: Are your methods returning IO, Future or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps follow a generator with a value definition using equals symbol for the calls that should execute in parallel

```
for {
  accDetails    <- fcaAndFplAccountDetails
  orgDetailsF   = orgDetailsIO(accDetails.orgId)
  unbilledTxnsF = unbilledTxnsIO(accDetails.orgId)
  orgDetails    <- orgDetailsF
  unbilledTxns  <- unbilledTxnsF 
} yield { ... further computations }
```

or convey the idea with [Applicative](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/applicative.html)

```
import cats.implicits._

fcaAndFplAccountDetails.flatMap { accDetails =>
  (
    orgDetailsIO(accDetails.orgId),
    unbilledTxnsIO(accDetails.orgId)
  ).mapN((orgDetails, unbilledTxns) => {
    ... further computations  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There must be dozens of options but one would be:

```
  val fcaAndFplAccountDetails : Future[Int] = ???
  def orgDetailsIO(orgId:Int)  : Future[_] = ???
  def unbilledTxns(orgid: Int) : Future[_] = ???
  for {
    accDetails   <- fcaAndFplAccountDetails
    (orgDetails, unbilledTxns)   <- Future.sequence(List(orgDetailsIO(accDetails), unbilledTxns(accDetails))).map(el => (el(0), el(1)))
} yield ()
```

You could use **Future.traverse** too

Comment: It's worth mentionning that as the name does NOT suggest `Future.sequence` do execute calls in **parallel**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056957/why-future-sequence-executes-my-futures-in-parallel-rather-than-in-series

Comment: @GaëlJ actually future starts executing at the time of creation only in a different thread. So `Future.sequence` is parallel as futures inside had already started their execution.