# Sequential execution of a list of an arbitrary number of Scala Futures

Tags: scala, promise, future

I read about [Scala Futures and Promises](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/futures-promises.html/).

I know that I can use callbacks, the `flatMap` combinator or a for-comprehension to chain futures. When a future is completed, another future is started and so on.

Is there a way to chain the execution of an arbitrary number of futures, stored in a Scala Collection (for example a `List`)?
I tried to invoke `Future.sequence` on this list of futures but they start all together and they are executed concurrently (not sequentially).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to do sequential execution of Futures in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414500/how-to-do-sequential-execution-of-futures-in-scala)

Comment: Your solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20415056/5123895 you need to provide list of items and function that can translate each of them into future, similarly to Future.traverse, but this will run sequentially. If you already have a list of futures then you have a problem because it's too late, they are already running.

Comment: I have tried with the solution reported in that link and it works. I read it before writing my post but it wasn't clear for me. Your explanation in the comment helped me to understand it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer is more care about how to deal a list of arbitrary number of **Scala Futures function**.

```
  type FUTURE_FUNCTION = String => Future[String]

  def compose(fs: List[FUTURE_FUNCTION]): FUTURE_FUNCTION = fs match {
    case List(head) => head
    case head :: tail => head(_).flatMap { u => compose(tail)(u) }
  }
```

In the above code snippet, create a **compose method** and **with high order Future function parameters**. and this method iterate all high order functions and compose a full new Future function.

Example Use:

```
  val f1: String => Future[String] =
    (s: String) => Future {
      s.toUpperCase
    }


  val f2: String => Future[String] =
    (s: String) => Future {
      s + " Hello World"
    }

  compose(List(f1, f2))("foo bar")
  > FOO BAR Hello World
```

Comment: I have tried with the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20415056/5123895), suggested by @Łukasz in a comment. It works and it is conceptually similar to your solution. I can't create a list of futures in advance but I need a function to obtain a Future from an "item". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def chainFutures(list: List[() => Future[Any]]): Future[Any] = {
  list match {
    case x :: Nil => Future.successful(x)
    case (x :: xs) => x() flatMap (_ => chainFutures(xs))
  }
}
```

this should do what you want, if you can accept to provide a list of functions that return a Future. The problem with a `List[Future[_]]` is, that they are already started, so they cant be chained in terms of execution. Except you provide a single thread `ExecutionContext`.

In case of failure, it returns the first failure and stops executing the other futures.

Comment: This simply doesn't do what was asked, when you pass a list of futures, they are all already started and run in parallel. And it does not accumulate results. And you call tail on xs while you probably meant xs which is already the tail of the list.

Comment: I found at least to answered question on SO that address your problem.See link to one in a comment to your question