# Scala - Batched Stream from Futures

Tags: scala, collections, future

I have instances of a case class `Thing`, and I have a bunch of queries to run that return a collection of `Thing`s like so:

```
def queries: Seq[Future[Seq[Thing]]]
```

I need to collect all `Thing`s from all futures (like above) and group them into equally sized collections of 10,000 so they can be serialized to files of 10,000 `Thing`s.

```
def serializeThings(Seq[Thing]): Future[Unit]
```

I want it to be implemented in such a way that I don't wait for all queries to run before serializing. As soon as there are 10,000 `Thing`s returned after the futures of the first queries complete, I want to start serializing.

If I do something like:

```
Future.sequence(queries)
```

It will collect the results of all the queries, but my understanding is that operations like `map` won't be invoked until all queries complete and all the `Thing`s must fit into memory at once.

What's the best way to implement a batched stream pipeline using Scala collections and concurrent libraries?

Comment: If you want to process N futures in batches of 10'000, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38255964/4496364) could help. Also, there is a bolg post from James Ward [here](https://www.jamesward.com/2016/06/16/reactive-web-request-batching-with-scala-and-play-framework/).

Comment: @insan-e I don't want to batch the futures. I want to batch the results of the futures which each future returns an arbitrary number of `Thing`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I managed to make something. The solution is based on my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38255964/4496364). It collects results from `Future[List[Thing]]` results until it reaches a treshold of `BatchSize`. Then it calls `serializeThings` future, when it finishes, the loop continues with the rest.

```
object BatchFutures extends App {

  case class Thing(id: Int)

  def getFuture(id: Int): Future[List[Thing]] = {
    Future.successful {
      List.fill(3)(Thing(id))
    }
  }

  def serializeThings(things: Seq[Thing]): Future[Unit] = Future.successful {
    //Thread.sleep(2000)
    println("processing: " + things)
  }

  val ids = (1 to 4).toList
  val BatchSize = 5

  val future = ids.foldLeft(Future.successful[List[Thing]](Nil)) {
    case (acc, id) =>
      acc flatMap { processed =>
        getFuture(id) flatMap { res =>
          val all = processed ++ res
          val (batch, rest) = all.splitAt(5)

          if (batch.length == BatchSize) { // if futures filled the batch with needed amount
            serializeThings(batch) map { _ =>
              rest // process the rest
            }
          } else {
            Future.successful(all) //if we need more Things for a batch
          }
        }
      }
  }.flatMap { rest =>
    serializeThings(rest)
  }

  Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)

}
```

The result prints:

> processing: List(Thing(1), Thing(1), Thing(1), Thing(2), Thing(2))
>   processing: List(Thing(2), Thing(3), Thing(3), Thing(3), Thing(4))
>   processing: List(Thing(4), Thing(4))

When the number of `Thing`s isn't divisible by `BatchSize` we have to call `serializeThings` once more(last `flatMap`). I hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Before you do `Future.sequence` do what you want to do with individual future and then use `Future.sequence`.

```
//this can be used for serializing
def doSomething(): Unit = ???

//do something with the failed future
def doSomethingElse(): Unit = ???

def doSomething(list: List[_]) = ???

val list: List[Future[_]] = List.fill(10000)(Future(doSomething()))

val newList = 
list.par.map { f =>
  f.map { result =>
    doSomething()
  }.recover { case throwable =>
    doSomethingElse()
  }
}

Future.sequence(newList).map ( list => doSomething(list)) //wait till all are complete
```

instead of `newList` generation you could use `Future.traverse`

```
Future.traverse(list)(f => f.map( x => doSomething()).recover {case th =>  doSomethingElse() }).map ( completeListOfValues => doSomething(completeListOfValues))
```