# Scala: from Seq to Sequential Futures

Tags: scala, dictionary, future, seq

I have a `Seq` of `Book` that I need to save to my database in the same order they are in the Seq. `Book.save` returns a `Future[Unit]`

If I write the following code, I know the save order may not be preserved:

`books.map(_.save)`

How can I sequentially execute these saves, but return the result as a `Future`?
Thanks!

Comment: This code can help to save the books in sequential http://stackoverflow.com/a/41657239

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use foldLeft:

```
val res:Future[Unit] = books.foldLeft(Future.successful {}) {
  case (acc, book) => acc.flatMap(_ => book.save)
}
```